# How do I make it redirect back to index page when on a unknow page?

Tags: redirect, indexing, html, back

so how do I do this?

Example:

yourdomain.com

and when someone types in a page that is not really there like this

yourdomain.com/whatevertheytype
yourdomain.com/whatevertheytype.php

ect

So how do i make it redirect it back to home when
the user is on a page that has nothing or not even
on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to setup a 404 error page. Details will vary depending on the server you are using but [here is a link with some tips](http://www.htaccessbasics.com/404-custom-error-page/)

Comment: really not a good idea, it's ok to customized not found page, but redirecting to an index will interfere with site indexing

Comment: I agree. I was just answering the 'how'..the 'should I' is a whole other question.